# Error generated when running unit test 'None'

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am new to python and trying to run a unit test. My function works well when using the print method, but while trying to develop a test module I keep getting errors.

my function in the python file(work.py)

```
def lee(n):
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print (i)
```

my unit test module

```
import unittest
import work

class TestWork(unittest.TestCase):
def test_lee(self):
result = work.lee(3)
self.assertEqual(result, [1,2,3])

if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

errors generated

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_lee (__main__.TestWork)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test_work.py", line 
12, in test_lee
self.assertEqual(result, [1,2,3])
AssertionError: None != [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Your function`lee` never returns a value.

Comment: @larsks identified the problem, but I wanted to add that indentation matters in python. In the future please make sure the indentations are preserved when you copy and paste your code into your question.

Comment: @larsks please how do I make lee function return the expected list.. when I use the print method it does

Comment: @lee create a list in the function `lee` and in the for-loop, append those values to the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here,

```
def lee(n):
    list = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        list.append(i)
    return list
```

As for printing, do `print(work.lee(3))`